# Viewing RDoc (Ruby Docs) Offline On Portable Device (iOS/Android/etc)

Tags: ruby, ipad, offline, rdoc, ri

I'd like to have offline access to RDoc generated pages so I can learn about a new gem or other software as I travel without Internet access. I prefer to use an iPad but this question is valid for any OS that does not easily support viewing a static website. As far as I can tell, RDoc doesn't have an option to generate single-page documentation or a big PDF. Is this correct? If so, is there an easy way to take RDoc files (basically a static website's files) and to turn them into some portable offline format?

Comment: RDoc is just HTML. Just find an HTML to PDF converter, and use iBooks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an HTML-to-PDF conversion tool to create a PDF file out of the HTML code generated by RDoc. [Pdfkit](https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit) is an excellent way to accomplish this:

```
require 'pdfkit'

kit = PDFKit.new(html, :page_size => 'Letter')
kit.stylesheets << '/path/to/css/file'
file = kit.to_file('/path/to/save/pdf')
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this is a poor solution because it only targets one page, not the entire site. Moreover, I ran it against index.html and it rendered two pages of blank PDFs.